# SPServices : GetUserProfile having only employee ID

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ldap, spservices

I want to use the SPService GetUserProfile, but I don't have the accountName, the GUID, the Index or the email... I only have a param which is employeeNumber (I guess this is specific to my compagnie).

I check on : http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UserProfileService, but I can't find how to do it.

**Is it possible to get a user profile searching with a specific param ?**

I can only use HTML/JS, I don't access to the server.

Comment: First, I don't think you can because even "_catalogs/users/simple.aspx" for sharepoint requires permission to view. Next if  employeed ID is configured in AD  then mapping should be created in Sharepoint. It depends on how Sharepoint is set-up. perhaps it is worth knowing explaining the configuration. For instance you can try http://<you sharepoint site>/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx to check if employee id is configured.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for all users who have at least logged into the site collection at some point. (The User Information List doesn't contain everyone from AD.) Sub your own values for `SITE`, `myFieldName`, and `myFieldValue`. `SITE` has to be the **site collection**, not a subsite.

```
<script src="PathToJQuery"></script>
<script src="PathToSPServices2014"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready( function(){

    SITE = "http://mysitecollection/";
    LIST = "User Information List";
    var myFieldName = "ows_JobTitle";
    var myFieldValue = "Electrician";

    var spPromise1 = $().SPServices({
        webURL: SITE,
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: LIST,
        async: false
    });

    spPromise1.done(function(){
        $(spPromise1.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr(myFieldName)==myFieldValue){
                console.log($(this).attr("ows_ID") + ": " + $(this).attr("ows_Title")); //Returns user ID and Display Name
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```